I'm getting lot of undefined reference errors while installing curl 8.8.0 even though I'm using latest version of openSSL 3.3.0
I downloaded the latest tar file from curl official site and trying it build it. I followed these steps :
cd curl-8.8.0
sudo ./configure --with-openssl
sudo make
but after I do sudo make at last I get these errors :
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/curl-8.8.0/src'
CCLD     curl
../lib/.libs/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get_group_name'
../lib/.libs/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `SSL_get0_group_name'
../lib/.libs/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get_security_bits'
../lib/.libs/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `X509_STORE_load_file'
../lib/.libs/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get_id'
../lib/.libs/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get_bits'
../lib/.libs/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `SSL_get1_peer_certificate'
../lib/.libs/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `X509_STORE_load_path'
../lib/.libs/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get_bn_param'
../lib/.libs/libcurl.so: undefined reference to `EVP_PKEY_get0_type_name'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:1048: curl] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/curl-8.8.0/src'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1553: all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/curl-8.8.0/src'
make: *** [Makefile:1224: all-recursive] Error 1

after a little searching on google, found out that it could be happening due to the older versions of openssl, so even I updated the openssl to the latest one:
$ openssl --version
OpenSSL 3.3.1 4 Jun 2024 (Library: OpenSSL 3.3.1 4 Jun 2024)

Host details :
$ uname -a
Linux alpps789 4.18.0-513.24.1.el8_9.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 14 14:20:09 EDT 2024 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ cat /etc/redhat-release
Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 8.10 (Ootpa)

Can anyone help me understand why this error is being thrown for libcurl.so and what steps to take to fix it?
I tried updating the openssl version as most of the communities saying its problem with older version of openssl.

Does this answer your question? What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?

It needs updated openssl development files. https://curl.se/mail/lib-2023-04/0040.html

I updated the openssl to the latest one  Where did you install OpenSSL 3.3?  Is your build of curl using the default RHEL 8 OpenSSL, which IIRC is OpenSSL 1.1.1?

@3CxEZiVlQ I think What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it? isn't a specific-enough dupe of this.  The EVP_PKEY_get_group_name missing symbol in the OP's error messages is an OpenSSL 3.0+ one, and wouldn't be available from OpenSSL 1.1.1.  And yet the build reached the link step?  I suspect something more is going on.

I asked the same question on curl github community. I got a reply saying it's using openSSL v3+ but libssl that is linked is an older one. How do I link new libssl now. I see that it's using libcul.so.4.8.0 which should be correct.

@3CxEZiVlQ, its already using latest openssl.

@AndrewHenle No, in the configuration summary I see that its using the latest installed version not the default.

@ShashankShekhar Linking against OpenSSL 3.3 libraries would not generate an error message such as ../lib/.libs/libcurl.so: undefined reference to \EVP_PKEY_get0_type_name'`

@AndrewHenle when I performed lld on libcurl.so, it's showing linked to older versions of libssl. $ sudo ldd libcurl.so         linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffdbe7df000)         libssh2.so.1 => /lib64/libssh2.so.1 (0x00007faac550c000)         libssl.so.1.1 => /lib64/libssl.so.1.1 (0x00007faac5278000)         libcrypto.so.1.1 => /lib64/libcrypto.so.1.1 (0x00007faac4d8d000)         libzstd.so.1 => /lib64/libzstd.so.1 (0x00007faac4ae9000)         libz.so.1 => /lib64/libz.so.1 (0x00007faac48d1000)       but how do I link it to the newer libssl

I was able to link the new libssl, and curl got installed succesfully but still when I check the curl version, its showing Openssl not available. $ curl --version curl 8.8.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/8.8.0 OpenSSL/not available zlib/1.2.11 zstd/1.4.4 due to this curl http requests are not working saying seg fault.

thanks for helping out. It's resolved now. Everything was correct. Only thing missing was libssl.so symlink present in /usr/lib64/ was pointing to the older libssl. Changed the symlink to point to the latest libssl and worked like wonders! Thanks all again.
